# python csv text file to array[i,j]

Tags: python, arrays, csv, matrix

I just started to learn python, so I need some help.

I have closeparams.txt file, it has CSV structure:

```
3;700;3;10;1
6;300;3;20;1
9;500;2;10;5
```

I need read this file to 2 dimension array. 
a[i,j] where i - is row and j - is column

I searched but not found exactly samples.
I will use this massive like this:

```
i=0
j=3
print a(i,j)
```

I suppose that display:

```
10
```

Or

```
i=2
j=1
print a(i,j)
```

I suppose that display:

```
500
```

Comment: what have you tried ? there are a lot of methods to load a csv file : csv module, numpy.genfromtxt, ...

Comment: there are also a lot of ways one could parse/interpret the example data you've provided?

Comment: I no problem with separated read and array working, but I stuck with working this two at at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
display_list = []

with open('closeparams.txt') as data_file:
   for line in data_file:
      display_list.append(line.strip().split(';'))

print(display_list[0][3]) # [i][j]
```

edit - python3 print()

Comment: change the print statement to a print function call; print()

Comment: or install numpy and try heltonbiker's solution

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use `numpy` if you want to deal with arrays. In your case:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.loadtxt('apaga.txt', delimiter=';')

print a[0,3]
```

You didn't specify how important will the array construct be for you, but Numpy is very, very powerful for complex tasks, and can be very lean to perform smaller, quick'n'dirty tasks in a compact, fast and readable way.

Comment: I have try something like this

Comment: import numpy

a = numpy.loadtxt(filename='closeparams.txt', delimiter=';')

print a[0,3]

Comment: Two possible causes: 1) you are using Python 3.x, if so then print(a[0,3]) should do; 2) you are putting everything in one line, if so then separate lines.

Comment: Yes, I use Python 3.1.1, I correct print(a[0,3]) but in shell -  import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: @RedSubmarine You have to install [`numpy`](http://numpy.scipy.org/) first. An alternative solution would be to use the built-in [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
import csv
sheet = list(csv.reader(open(source_path)))
print sheet[0][0]
```

Just typecast the opened csv to a list!

Comment: Your post has shown up in the Low Quality Posts review queue. This is likely because you haven't provided any explanation. Your code is fairly clear, so I am going to mark this answer "Looks OK", but explained code has greater potential to be helpful.